# What is the currently most equivalent framework to React.js in Java?

Tags: java, reactive-programming

I'm trying to introduce reactive programming to my coworkers, who do Java. I myself am familiar with Reagent in ClojureScript.

If you want to do reactive programming in Java, and you want to experience something very similar to React.js, what do you use?

I know the DOM diffing is of course out of the equation, but while I am aware that there are functional reactive frameworks for Java, I'm too inexperienced with both "raw" React.js and these frameworks to point to the most equivalent one. And, actually, I don't know if functional reactive programming == reactive programming.

Comment: Are you asking about Rx? like [Reactive-Extensions](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) in JavaScript?  Or about Facebook's react.js (a JavaScript UI building tool)?

Comment: For reactive programming in Java likke at [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava).

Comment: I'm talking about Facebook's react.js.